# Xamarin.Forms: Upgrading from 2.3.4 to 3.0 caused Android Contents to extend past bottom

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I had to update a year-old app to the current version of forms. Unfortunately on Android, it seems to think the screen is taller then it actually is (see screen shot). Everything is working just fine for iOS, but all my pages are slightly taller than the screen on Android on multiple devices.

[image]

Some things I have tried:

- Made sure I'm using the latest SDK's and latest Android Support files
- Hacked in a paddingEv
- Updated all my custom renderers with the new android constructors

Layout description:
Depends on the idiom: On a phone, it's a MasterDetail with a Tabbed Page as Detail, a Navigation Page for the first Child of Tabbed Page (so Menu appears for only that page), and Content Pages for the rest. For Tablet, the Children of the Tabbed pages are all Content Pages. Modal Pages are all Content Pages.

Any help, even diagnostically, would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

My current hack is to adjust the padding in a special renderer like so:

```
public class HackLayoutShiftFixRenderer : MasterDetailPageRenderer
{
    public HackLayoutShiftFixRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElement oldElement, VisualElement newElement)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(oldElement, newElement);

        if (!(newElement is MasterDetailPage masterDetail)) return;

        masterDetail.Master.Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 24);
        masterDetail.Detail.Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 24);
    }
}
```

And I do something similar with modal pages. The number 24 was used with trial and error.

Comment: Hi, would you mind provide the project on github?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have permission to do that :(.

Comment: Scratch that, I'll see if I can load the Android part in a separate project sometime today or tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, but wouldn't mind some clarification as to why this happened.

A year ago, this was implemented to fix the keyboard hiding search items on a Listview: http://xamarinformscorner.blogspot.com/2016/06/soft-keyboard-hiding-entries-fields-in.html

*Code in case the link disappears:*

```
public class AndroidBug5497WorkaroundForXamarinAndroid
{

    // For more information, see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5497
    // To use this class, simply invoke assistActivity() on an Activity that already has its content view set.

    // CREDIT TO Joseph Johnson (http://stackoverflow.com/users/341631/joseph-johnson) for publishing the original Android solution on stackoverflow.com

    public static void assistActivity(Activity activity)
    {
        new AndroidBug5497WorkaroundForXamarinAndroid(activity);
    }

    private View mChildOfContent;
    private int usableHeightPrevious;
    private FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutParams;

    private AndroidBug5497WorkaroundForXamarinAndroid(Activity activity)
    {
        FrameLayout content = (FrameLayout)activity.FindViewById(global::Android.Resource.Id.Content);
        mChildOfContent = content.GetChildAt(0);
        ViewTreeObserver vto = mChildOfContent.ViewTreeObserver;
        vto.GlobalLayout += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
            possiblyResizeChildOfContent();
        };
        frameLayoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)mChildOfContent.LayoutParameters;
    }

    private void possiblyResizeChildOfContent()
    {
        int usableHeightNow = computeUsableHeight();
        if (usableHeightNow != usableHeightPrevious)
        {
            int usableHeightSansKeyboard = mChildOfContent.RootView.Height;
            int heightDifference = usableHeightSansKeyboard - usableHeightNow;

            frameLayoutParams.Height = usableHeightSansKeyboard - heightDifference;

            mChildOfContent.RequestLayout();
            usableHeightPrevious = usableHeightNow;
        }
    }

    private int computeUsableHeight()
    {
        Rect r = new Rect();
        mChildOfContent.GetWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
        {
            return (r.Bottom - r.Top);
        }
        return r.Bottom;
    }
```

The problem was in the "computeUsableHeight" function: At least with the latest version, I must always take the difference between the top and bottom into account. I don't know why or when this changed between Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4 & 3.0